# Check for duplicate custom field value before running wp_insert_post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wp-insert-post, post-duplication

That is, I want to prevent 'guid_review' ACF value being duplicate by checking it before creating the post.

```
foreach ($items as $itemKey => $item) {


            $myPost = array(
                'post_type' => 'client_review',
                'post_title' =>(string) $item->title, //the object as a string before attempting to manipulate it.
                'post_content' =>(string) $item->description                

            );


            $inserted_post_id = wp_insert_post( (array) $myPost );



            if( $inserted_post_id ){

                add_post_meta( (int) $inserted_post_id,'guid_review',(string)$item->guid);
                add_post_meta($inserted_post_id,'link_review',(string)$item->link);
                add_post_meta($inserted_post_id,'author_review',(string)$item->author);
                add_post_meta($inserted_post_id,'rating_review',(string)$item->children('d3', true)->rating);
                add_post_meta($inserted_post_id,'certified_review',(string)$item->children('d3', true)->certified);
                add_post_meta($inserted_post_id,'pub_date_review',(string)$item->pubDate);              

            }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a `WP_query` using `meta_key` and `meta_value` args

Take a look here [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

If the result is non - empty - you know you have a duplicate!

Comment: Please add more detail (code) to your answer as an explanation to what you mean

Comment: Actually am trying to insert XML data into a custom post type called 'Reviews'.I have successfully inserted each of them as a post where each post would have a unique ID determined by a variable $inserted_post_id.But only the way I can prevent my XML information from duplicating while inserting is by filtering by an unique identifier on XML data which is 'guid'.So going back to my question,I want to check whether guid value is 
already inserted into database or not.I have set guid and other require field through ACF plugin.So where in the code above should I query the DB and how would that be?

Comment: In above 'guid_review' is a custom field I have created to store the value that comes from '$item->guid' .